# Excel conditional formatting for x/y

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have multiple columns that contains data in the format below.

[image]

I want to highlight the cells that have non zero denominator as red.
So 2/4 should be highlighted as red but not others.

I am unable to figure out how to do this. Please help.

Comment: If I select `A2:A12` and use formatting formula `=RIGHT(A2,2)<>"/0"` I got your desired result.

Comment: Thank you. it works but it doesn't handle blank cells. They are also highlighted. I don't want to factor in the blank cells. What can i do ?

Comment: Thank you @JvdV for guiding me in the right direction. I was able to figure out that to exclude blank cells, i use the below formula

=AND(NOT(ISBLANK(B2)),RIGHT(B2,2)<>"/0")

Answer (score 1):

To ignore blank cells you need to add another condition. Try below-

```
=AND(RIGHT($A1,2)<>"/0",$A1<>"")
```

[image]